# I have these extra faces which needs deleting. Is there any solution to this?

Tags: modeling

[image: mo]

I dissolved edges in top surface to made it plain, but i have these extra faces that are giving me hard time. I'm still learning basics.

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aS6bPrvg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aS6bPrvg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices or vertices that are not connected, you should first delete the bottom face:

[image]

Then select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

And select the bottom edge loop and fill again:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's one big concave face not displaying correctly. Try to avoid having massively concave faces, because this happens with them. Maybe join some vertices near the problem with another parts of geometry:

[image]

You can use knife tool for that (<kbd>k</kbd>) or select vertices and hit <kbd>j</kbd> to join them by an edge.